# Cascade deleting many-to-one relationship with EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

i'm designing code-first database using Entity Framework 6 for small project and want to enable cascade deleting of orphaned data. Let's assume I have following entities:

```
public class Document
{
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public Guid DocumentSourceId { get; set; }
    public Guid? DocumentResultId { get; set; }

    public virtual DocumentSource DocumentSource { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentResult DocumentResult { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentSource
{
    public Guid DocumentSourceId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentResult
{
    public Guid DocumentResultId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

I can configure deleting of DocumentResult with following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
    .HasOptional(d => d.DocumentResult)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

But i can't figure out how to configure cascade deleting of DocumentSource. Document-DocumentSource in many-to-one relationship, e.g. many Documents can have same Source, so I want DocumentSource to be deleted when there is no more Document left referencing on it. Can this be achieved with EF 6?

Comment: A many-to-one cascading delete simply isn't possible in a relational database. I'm curious to see if there is a simple way in EF to simulate this behavior though.